# TranslateBehavior in CakePHP 5 expects a non-existent table: Base table or view not found

Tags: cakephp

I try to migrate an v2.x cakephp project to v5.x.

My categories table has content in different languages in the **i18n** table (default schema from config/schema/i18n.sql).

When I now enable the Behavior in the CategoriesTable model:

```
public function initialize(array $config): void
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->setTable('categories');
    $this->setDisplayField('title');
    $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

    $this->addBehavior('Translate', [
        'fields' => ['title']
    ]);
```

I receive this Error:

**SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table ‘my_database.categories_translations’ doesn’t exist**
Please try correcting the issue for the following table aliases:

- CategoriesTranslations
- CategoriesTranslation

Why does the Translate Behavior is expecting a categories_translations table?

Thanks for your help!

## Update now with:

```
    $this->addBehavior('Translate', [
        'strategyClass' => Cake\ORM\Behavior\Translate\EavStrategy::class,
        'fields' => ['title']
    ]);
```

**CakePHP 2 Query (works):**

```
SELECT `Category`.`id`, (`I18n__title`.`content`) AS `Category__i18n_title`
FROM `dgp_wegweiser`.`categories` AS `Category`
         INNER JOIN `dgp_wegweiser`.`i18n` AS `I18n__title`
                    ON (`Category`.`id` = `I18n__title`.`foreign_key` AND `I18n__title`.`model` = 'Category' AND
                        `I18n__title`.`field` = 'title' AND `I18n__title`.`locale` = 'en')
WHERE `Category`.`is_for_children` = '0'
ORDER BY `Category`.`category_order` ASC
```

**CakePHP 5 Query:** (with the enabled EavStrategy)

```
SELECT
    Categories.id AS Categories__id,
    Categories.title AS Categories__title,
    Categories_title_translation.id AS Categories_title_translation__id,
    Categories_title_translation.content AS Categories_title_translation__content
FROM
    categories Categories
        LEFT JOIN i18n Categories_title_translation ON (
                Categories_title_translation.model = 'Categories'
            AND Categories_title_translation.field = 'title'
            AND Categories_title_translation.locale = 'en'
            AND Categories.id = Categories_title_translation.foreign_key
        )
WHERE is_for_children = FALSE
ORDER BY category_order ASC
```

**The CakePHP 5 Translate Behavior does not read the translated content.** :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does so, because as of 5.x the default strategy of the translate behavior is the "Shadow Table" strategy:

> `TranslateBehavior` now defaults to the `ShadowTable` strategy. If you are using the `Eav` strategy you will need to update your behavior configuration to retain the previous behavior.

**https://book.cakephp.org/5/en/appendices/5-0-migration-guide.html#orm**

Be sure to carefully read through all the 4.x/5.x migration guides to catch all the (breaking) changes that might affect your code.

tl;dr, if you want to keep using the `Eav` strategy, then you'll have to pass the `strategyClass` option accordingly:

```php
$this->addBehavior('Translate', [
    'fields' => ['title', 'title_singular', 'caption', 'description', 'slug'],
    'strategyClass' => \Cake\ORM\Behavior\Translate\EavStrategy::class,
]);
```

**https://book.cakephp.org/5/en/orm/behaviors/translate.html**

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the missed RTFM! Now Cake is using the correct table. But the sql query doesn't read the correct content. See my update in the question.

Comment: @hasentopf The query looks fine. Make sure that your DB contains the required data, as for example the `model` field content needs to be different now (`Category` vs `Categories`). Also manually run the queries directly against your DB to figure what exactly they return.

Comment: Thanks @ndm! The solution is: 'referenceName' => 'Category', Now it works!